# how to create an arraylist within super(...)

Tags: java, super

A parent class:

```
public abstract class Gate implements Logic{
  private List<Wire> inputs;
  private Wire output;
  private String name;

  public Gate(String name, List<Wire> ins, Wire out){
  }
```

A child class:

```
public class GateNot extends Gate{
  public GateNot(Wire input, Wire output){  

    super("Not",new ArrayList(input) ,output);//this is apparently incorrect.

  }
```

Parameters in GateNot's constructor is different from parameters in the parent class. I want to create an arraylist and pass input into this arraylist, so that super(...) would work. How can I create this arraylist in super(..)? If an arraylist does not work here, what can I do with this super?

Comment: `new ArrayList<Wire>(input)`?

Comment: can ArrayList be passed instead of List?

Comment: What doesn't work?  This is the same question as you were asking yesterday isn't it.

Comment: they are different. I just start learning arraylist. I am just trying to understand better. I have my own idea but do not know how to put it into real codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you only have one input. So..

```
public class GateNot extends Gate {
    public GateNot(Wire input, Wire output) {
        super("Not", new ArrayList<Wire>(Arrays.asList(input)), output);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I realised you have a List<> instead of an ArrayList<> so we can simplify this to:

```
public class GateNot extends Gate {
    public GateNot(Wire input, Wire output) {
        super("Not", Arrays.asList(input), output);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can use Arrays directly here and dont have to create a new array like Wire[] a?

Comment: Arrays.asList() returns a List<>. You *have* to provide a List<> because it's in the parent constructor.